# Django Views redirect('homepage')

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm stuck and don't understand why here my problem:

- I would like to return context if objects exists else redirect to homepage and raise error Objects.DoesNotExist.

Here My Code :

Views

```
class PageDetail(TemplateView):
    """
    Page View
    """
    template_name = 'page_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            context['news'] = News.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-date_created')[:4]
        except:
            pass
        try:
            context['page'] = Pages.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('slug'), is_active=True)
        except Pages.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('homepage')
        return context
```

But I got this error :

```
raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
```

Tell me if you need more infos

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a TemplateView, I would suggest using a DetailView. You could override get_context_data() in a similar fashion, to pass the extra info (news). there is no need to pass 'page' as this is what the DetailView is designed to do for you.

Then you could override get() to redirect to the home page if the page isn't found, rather than the default behaviour which is to raise a Http404 error.

For example:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.object = self.get_object()
    except Http404:
        return redirect('homepage')
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**Update:** You can use 'context_object_name', to allow you to refer to page in your template, rather than self.object, as follows:

```
class Page(DetailView):
    model = Pages
    template_name = 'page_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'page'
```

P.s. It appears that your model is called Pages, it might make more sense for it to be called Page, as (I assume) each instance is a single page.

Comment: Thank you, for this clearly explanation, It's definitely smarter to do it this way. But I got one more question : I added a BooleanField in Page Model called is_active.
How can I return context if self.object.is_active == True else return redirect('homepage')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I've used your solution and add if statement to return context if page is active
else redirect to homepage.

In my views.py

```
class PageDetail(DetailView):
model = Pages
template_name = 'page_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'page'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PageDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        context['news'] = News.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-date_created')[:4]
    except:
        pass
    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.object = self.get_object()
    except Http404:
        return redirect('homepage')
    if self.object.is_active:
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    else:
        return redirect('homepage')
```